# How to restore rewritten version of CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, restore

I'm new to Raspberry Pi world and Python 3. I have written some program for logging data from sensors of my RPi. The data is being written to a CSV file but with 'w' which means that the previous version of the file deletes and the file is being rewritten every next time. Today I wrote my data to the file but I forgot and rewrote the new version of the file. And now I want to restore the previous file CSV with the same name. Remember that the files are saved to the SD card of the RPi not on a hard drive in the RPi...
I need help very much, please help somebody!

Comment: Your data's gone.

Comment: in reference to file recovery for "deleted" files see : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/file_recovery